# Reg Ex for specific numbers at beginning of string - 0800 OR 00800

Tags: regex

I need a reg ex to validate '0800' or '00800' at beginning of string eg:

008005912117 - OK 
008008841788 - OK
0022981650800 - NOK
08007260207 - OK
0035991940800 - NOK

I'm trying with this regex but is not working with 00800, can be simple the reg EX?

```
^1\d\d(\d\d)?$|^0800 ?\d{3} ?\d{4}$|
```

Comment: Maybe you need to replace `^0800` with `^0?0800`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that your line starts with `0800` or `00800` just use:

```
^0?0800.*
```

Note that:

```
^0800 ?\d{3} ?\d{4}$
       ^^^^^  ^^^^^
```

Force your string to contains 11 digits. If you want to keep this kind of format, you can make it optional:

```
^0800( ?\d{3} ?\d{4})?$
     ^              ^^
```